# How do I use fetched data in the return / jsx part of my React component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch data but its always undefined once it gets to my return.. which makes sense because I am no longer using .then at that point. React doesnt seem to let me make the function Async so I cant really use await either? I tried setting it with useState but its still undefined where I need to use the data.

```
    const [myData,setData] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://recipesapi2.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/tomato%20soup', options)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.data); console.log('this is my data', data.data)
       })
      .then(()=>console.log(myData))
  },[])   
  
  return(
    <div>{myData[0].name}</div>
  )  }
```

I would also like to note that if I remove the return, and then wait for the page to respond with the data in the log, then add  the return info back, it displays the div info properly. However, if i hard refresh the browser it runs nothing, not even my console logs. So that tells me I am inputting the proper code to populate the div but its not awaiting the fetch and just throwing errors.

Comment: Where you have `setData(data.data)`, make it `setData(data.data); console.log('this is my data', data.data);` so you can debug it. And let us know what it prints

Comment: Also `.then(console.log(myData))` doesn't make sense. It should probably be `.then(() => { console.log(myData); })` and while we're at it, it's better to make it a `.then(() => { console.log(myData); }).catch((e) => { console.log('error!', e); })`

Comment: here is what that logs... I removed my return cause it doesnt run with what i am trying to return...  
this is my data 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{name: 'The Best Ever Tomato Soup', ingredients: Array(15), instructions: Array(2), nutrients: {…}, tags: Array(0), …}

I removed the rest of the items in the array because in my example I am only trying to access the 0 index

also, I did realize my console log did not have the arrow function before it and fixed it after my initial post. Thanks. I had it in there at one point but in troubleshooting I forgot to add it back.

Comment: Can you update the snippet on the question with what you have at the moment? Including the removal of `0` and addition of the arrow function (and else)? This should make it easier for us to talk under a common ground

Comment: I updated the  code and added a little more information that i recently noticed as well.

Comment: You have initalize `myData ` with '' and trying to access ` <div>{myData[0].name}</div>` in first step .So before Api calls return runs and it will give you error.So there are two ways.Either initialize myData properly or put a check in return while accessing `myData[0].name`. You can do something like `{myData.length && myData[0].name}`

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue. I am a little confused as to why though and maybe  you can point out something I am missing.
    {myData.length && myData[0].name}
So according to MDN, This would return the first falsy or the last truthy if they are both truthy. However, how is it returning the length until the data is returned? Wouldnt the length be truthy and the data be falsy? By that logic I would expect it to return the data ( aka undefined ) or, the data after it loads. I dont see who it is ever returning the length ( or any truthy value in the first part of the expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error because `myData[0]` is initially an empty string, so you cannot get the name property until the data have been loaded. Just add a check for myData.

```
  const [myData,setData] = useState('')
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://recipesapi2.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/tomato%20soup', options)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.data); console.log('this is my data', data.data)
       })
      .then(()=>console.log(myData))
  },[])   
  
  if (!myData || !myData.length) return <div>No data</div>

  return (
    <div>{myData[0]?.name}</div>
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have been thinking like this. However, assuming react had something in place for this scenario, I spent more time looking for something that doesnt exist and no time actually solving my problem in the event react didnt have a built in solution.

However, can you explain why you have a ? in the return and what its checking? I'v never seen it used like that.
        <div>{myData[0]?.name}</div>

Comment: This is an optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining. It doesn't necessary in this situation, but still you can add it to handle when myData[0] doesn't have name property.